# Prove that K is not compact

Tags: general-topology

Hello I have problems with this exercise

Consider the metric space $\mathbb{Q}$ of rational numbers with the Euclidean distance.
Prove that: $K= \{ x\in \mathbb{Q} |  0 \leq{x} \leq{\sqrt[ ]{2}} \}$

is closed and bounded, yet not compact.

My attempt:

It is clear that it is closed and bounded

To prove that is not compact, I have to prove there exists an open coating from which you cannot extract a finite subcoating.

For example $U_n= \{ x\in \mathbb{Q} |  0 <x< \sqrt[ ]{2}-\dfrac{1}{n} \}$
I have to prove that they are open and cover $K$

How do I prove that they cover K?

Comment: I am not sure it makes complete sense to write such things in your metric space: $x< \sqrt[ ]{2}-\dfrac{1}{n}$, since the root of 2 is not in your world.

Comment: Be careful: clearly $K$ is closed and bounded *when seen as a subset of the metric space R*, but you are working in the metric space Q.

Comment: It is not clear that they are open and compact

Comment: What about this. For each $q\in \mathbb{Q}\cap[0,\sqrt{2}]$ take $d_q=\sqrt{2}-q>0$ and set $U_q=(-\infty,q+d_q/2)\cap \mathbb{Q}$. Can you show that $\{U_q\}_{q\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,\sqrt{2}]}$ is an open cover of $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,\sqrt{2}]$ with no finite subcover?

Comment: I think I can prove it